# Why won't my ActionResult read this jQuery AJAX post value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using a JQuery-based pagination tool on a simple table graph and need to send the selected page number to the ActionResult that is generating a LINQ query, so it can properly page the results. However, when I attempt to pass the page number via the $.ajax call I am using to grab the data, my ActionResult does not get the posted value. What am I doing wrong?

$.ajax call:

(I have confirmed that this function is inheriting the page number. I have also confirmed via FireBug that the "pagenum" parameter is being posted):

```
function refreshBoard(inputValue, pageNumber) {
    var job;
    var myurl = '/Search/GetItems/' + inputValue
    var mydata = "pagenum = " + pageNumber;
    $.ajax({
        data: mydata,
        url: myurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
```

ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetItems(string id)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Request["pagenum"]); //<-- Does not work. X is always 0
        //..... More code .....
```

Comment: `x` is 0, but what is `Request["pagenum"]`?  What is `pageNumber`?  What are the values being sent in the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Add that as your parameter.parameter Model binding will set the value from your request to the parameter. You may use a default value (1) also so that if the caller is not sending that value, it will be set as 1 (the default value we give)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItems(string id,int pagenum=1)
{
   //use the "pagenum" variable now
   //to do : return something
}
```

You can either send the pagenum in querystring

```
var myurl = '/Search/GetItems/' + inputValue+"?pagenum="+pageNumber
```

or you can send JSON structure like this

```
var mydata = { "pagenum" : pageNumber }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem why it's not working is probably because you're not sending JSON as data. Therefore I recommend you to change your code as what follows. You are also posting to `'/search/GetItems/' + pageNumber`, this post should be done to `'/search/GetItems/'` instead.

#### Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {id: inputValue, pageNum:pageNumber},
    url: '/Search/GetItems',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    }
```

#### Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItems(string id, int pageNum)
{
}
```

The JSON data **must** match with the parameters on the serverside!